# How to replace a value of an attribute in xml using Python minidom

Tags: python, xml, replace, minidom

I have the following xml:

```
<country name="Liechtenstein">
    <rank>1</rank>
    <year>2008</year>
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    <neighbor direction="E" name="Austria"/>
    <neighbor direction="W" name="Switzerland"/>
</country>
```

I want to replace the value "Liechtenstein" with "Germany", so the result should look like:

```
<country name="Germany">
    <rank>1</rank>
    <year>2008</year>
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    <neighbor direction="E" name="Austria"/>
    <neighbor direction="W" name="Switzerland"/>
</country>
```

So far I am up to this point:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('C:/Users/Torah/Desktop/country.xml')
print xmldoc.toxml()
country = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("country")
firstchild = country[0]
print firstchild.attributes["name"].value
#simple string mathod to replace
print firstchild.attributes["name"].value.replace("Liechtenstein", "Germany")
print xmldoc.toxml()
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I can access the value, but don't know how to replace it.

Comment: It's better to include the code that you have so it can be updated / modified to replace the value.

Answer (score 5):

The following line does not actually change the XML:

```
print firstchild.attributes["name"].value.replace("Liechtenstein", "Germany")
```

It only gets the value, replaces Liechtenstein with Germany in that string and prints that string. It does not modify the value in the XML document.

You should assign a new value directly:

```
firstchild.attributes["name"].value = "Germany"
```

Answer (score 3):

Simeon's line does work.

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
firstchild.setAttribute('name', 'Germany')
```